# How to add .json files to array, and echo one of these

Tags: php, json, file, testing

I have a couple of .json files on a server. i want to add them all to an array.

```
$jsonFiles = array(<all the .json files>);
echo $jsonFiles[3]
```

And echo one of these. For testing purposes.

i'm new to PHP, and dont know the syntax

EDIT: i want to echo the content of the file

Comment: Do you want to read the file contents or just the file names?

Comment: the contents of the file, so that i can use it in other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the content of a file, use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). The function to get files in a directory is called [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

For your example, use:

```
echo file_get_contents($jsonFiles[3]);
```